# map function in Erlang

Tags: list, lambda, functional-programming, erlang, prolog

In addition to having the map function available with many arities (up to 4), Prolog allows you (under certain circumstances) to map a multiple arity function onto a single list.  Say you want to test whether 'x' is a member of multiple lists.  You can do:

```
maplist(member(x),[[a,b,c,x],[3,f,s,x]]).
```

The first argument of member is included, and the whole thing is mapped onto the list.

**Question 1:**  Is something similar available to Erlang?  I can't find it in the documentation, but then again I can't find it in any Prolog documentation either.

**Question 2:**  How to use map (and similar functions) with multiple arities?  Roll your own?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like:

```
23> lists:map(fun(L) -> lists:member(42,L) end, [[1,5,8,4],[13,42],[7,2,10]]).
[false,true,false]
24>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are `lists:map/2` and also list comprehensions:

```
1> lists:map(fun(L) -> lists:member(42,L) end, [[1,5,8,4],[13,42],[7,2,10]]).
[false,true,false]
2> [ lists:member(42,L) || L <- [[1,5,8,4],[13,42],[7,2,10]] ].
[false,true,false]
```